# Labeling of elements/objects.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, logic, notation

I wondered if there are any formal restrictions to symbols we give to objects. I know that this question is basic, but I didn't really know a definite explanation to this, since this has rather been "taken for granted", but perhaps there is something explicit that allows this, that I did not think about before. Consider the following two examples.

$(1)$ Let $X,Y$ be sets and $f:X \to Y$ be a function. Then, by definition, for all $x \in X$ there exists a $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$. Then by $f(x)$ we mean the object $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$. We thus define $f(x):=y$ for this specific $y$, why can we do that?

$(2)$ Let $X$ be a finite set. Then there exists an $n \in \mathbf{N}$ as well as $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. Why is this the case? By definition, since $X$ is finite, there exists a bijective function $f: \{1,...,n\} \to X$. Now I can define $x_i:=f(i)$ for all $i=1,...,n$. Why can I define $x_i$ this way? Are there any restrictions/formal limitations to the degree of which I can do this? One of them would be, that I can't use symbols that are used in this context before, however, are there others?

I didn't really know how to tag this question, so if there are better tags I appreciate an edit.

Comment: (1) if $f$ is a *function* thus means, by definition, that for every $x$ in the *domain* of definition of the function there is **exactly one** $y$ such that the function outputs the value $y$ for input value $x$. Thus, we write $f(x)$ to denote that output value.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, but I wondered why I can do so. Can I just name existing objects whatever I like?

Comment: In what context? In general, we can "add" a new name to the language of a specified theory, provided that we have proved that the corresponding object exists.

Comment: About (2): $x_i$ is another way to denote the $i$-th element of $X$, i.e. $f(i)$. Exactly as when we "label" the house in a road with civic numbers: we are "bijecting" the finite set of houses with an initial segment of $\mathbb N$.